# Xcode access attributes inside user defined runtime attributes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I need to set the cornerRadius of my button to its own width squared. I know I can do this programmatically, but I need to do it in the storyboard (dev team standards).

So basically I need to do this:

```
bigCircle.layer.cornerRadius = bigCircle.bounds.size.width ^ 2
```

In here:

[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that's possible. A runtime attributes value must be a constant, not a variable / property.